# image scroller using yui

Tags: image, yui, scroll

Can any one tell me how to implement a yui carousel based image scroller ?
Will it also respond to mouse wheel event as well ?

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/carousel/csl_circular.html

However,  the carousel is a YUI2 widget, mousewheel events are supported in YUI3 (but not, as far as I can tell, in 2).  So you are out of luck with mousewheel + carousel in YUI2.  You could use the event outside of YUI and create a custom event to subscribe to and run your callbacks from that.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScriptReference/Javascript-Properties/wheelDeltaExample.htm